# Making an emoji-enabeling app for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod-touch

I know they sell a lot of apps in the [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_(iOS/iPadOS)) that claim to "unlock" emoji keyboards. How would I go about doing this?

I want to made an app that enables emoji keyboards. I have paid the 100 dollar developers license fee if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Based on one of the samples provided in the links above you can do the following:

```
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                  @"../../Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preferences.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *dict =
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"KeyboardEmojiEverywhere"];
[dict writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```

Comment: Still works with iOS 4+ but you have to kill the settings application for the Emoji keyboard to appear in the "Add New Keyboard" list.

Comment: is we need to add image for new emoji? or we have to use unicodes to create different emoji?

Answer (score 2):

See *[iPhone devs, access Emoji for free with Freemoji](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2009/02/freemoji-access-emoji-for-free.ars)*.

Comment: While this tells you that you CAN enable emjoii's using Apps purchased from the App Store, it doesn't answer this question by telling you HOW to do in code by yourself...

Comment: He links to three different examples of how to implement it?  What more do you really want?