# Create custom international keyboard for iPhone

Tags: ios, internationalization, keyboard, emoji

Is it possible to take advantage of the international keyboard feature for the iPhone and create a custom keyboard that can be used over the entire phone not just within a particular app?

Similar to the Emoji keyboard but I'm under the impression that's somehow native to iOS and is just disabled by default?

I've looked at a lot of the questions on here regarding this, I'd just like to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [Apple's submission guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

- 2.5 Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected
- 2.6 Apps that read or write data outside its designated container area will be rejected

There are no public APIs to add an additional keyboard.

The files that store keyboard data are definitely stored outside of your app's container.

In short: There is no way to implement a custom global keyboard on a non-jailbroken iOS device at this point in time.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 8 you can now create custom keyboard extensions: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score -1):

**@0x90**

this App adds an international keyboard to iOS (a keyboard you will see in your iOS general settings)

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/emoji-free!/id332509635?mt=8

how did they manage to do it?

--

**EDIT:** i'm sorry for not searching it before, this should be the answer

[Making An Emoji Enabeling App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225514/making-an-emoji-enabeling-app/1239449#1239449)

Comment: they don't add custom keyboard, just enable functionality that is already present in iOS...

Answer (score -1):

The best way i found is to add shortcuts. 
Go in the keyboard setting and paste the symbols you copied from a document or safari and give it a shortcut. For exemple: for √ i used ss. So i just double the first letter of the thing. Or for an exponent like ², i just use 22. 
It takes a while to setup but its an easy way instead of switching between the symbol app and do a copy and paste every time. And for greek symbols, i just installed the greek keyboard. 
Have fun.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.