# how to create and install own keyboard (like emoji) which we can use in any application?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, emoji, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

emoji keyboard is being enabled on device when we enable the key **KeyboardEmojiEverywhere** in the plist file **/private/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preferences.plist**

So,just with a key how can we get a keyboard? What is logic behind that?

I want to create my custom keyboard like emoji and want to install it on iphone,so that i can use it with any application with pressing globe button.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create custom international keyboard for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556647/create-custom-international-keyboard-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 8, Apple has made it possible to create custom keyboard that user can access throughout the device(in other applications also).
Please check [Keyboard Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html).

You can create your own custom keyboard using Keyboard extension. You can check a nice tutorial [here](http://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/).