# Input Method Editor - ios 8

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ime

Does anybody know some examples to customized a keyboard in ios ?
I know that now is impossible to do [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9171950/757696), but ios8 would permit this feature. So I guess that someone is doing this right now.

Some proofs:

- [Flesky](http://fleksy.com/ios8/)
- [Swype](http://www.swype.com/get-swype/swype-on-ios-2/)
- [Swiftkey](http://swiftkey.com/ios/)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a library to create customized keyboards - https://github.com/Brimizer/Slidden

The goal is to get you up and running with a basic keyboard very easily. 
Simple as creating a few keys and adding them to the keyboard.

```
func setupKeys() {
    let helloKey = KeyboardKeyView(type: .Character, keyCap: "Hello", outputText: "Hello")
    helloKey.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    helloKey.color = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.keyboardView.addKey(helloKey, row: 0)

    let worldKey = KeyboardKeyView(type: .Character, keyCap: "World", outputText: "World")
    worldKey.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    worldKey.color = UIColor.redColor()
    self.keyboardView.addKey(worldKey, row: 0)
}
```