# Custom Cordova IOS keyboard

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, iphone-softkeyboard

I am working on a Cordova app for which the client insists we have a custom keyboard for numeric input that looks native; the goal is similar to a keyboard that comes up with PayPal.

Here is the problem: we need to do this without touching the way things work for Android in our app. This probably means we need to create a cordova plugin, but I have read that creating custom keyboard is looked down on by the folks over at Apple (see [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556647/create-custom-international-keyboard-for-iphone) about it).

I've had a very difficult time finding any documentation on how to do this with Cordova on IOS, which makes me lean towards rolling a solution inside of Cordova using a jquery library. My question has two parts:

1: If possible, how does one create a custom keyboard for html5 inputs in Cordova as an IOS plugin?

2: If this is a lost cause, what existing jquery plugins would you recommend instead?