# create a customized global keyboard for iPhone or iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

I am wondering if it is now possible to create your own custom global keyboard for an iPhone, a similar question was asked some years ago:

[Create custom international keyboard for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556647/create-custom-international-keyboard-for-iphone/6556672#6556672)

Is the following possible in iOS v7:

1. I build and install an iphone application
2. the application registers a custom keyboard (as an international keyboard)
3. this keyboard can be used anywhere (eg sms, etc)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, iOS doesn't support custom keyboard (like Android)