# How to customize keyboard with number together on Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard, numbers

Apple released keyboard Telex for Vietnamese, but in Vietnam much people use VNI for text Vietnamese. That why today I have a question how can I customize keyboard with number together like this screen short of an app? 
Vietnamese want use VNI text input need have number with keyboard together.

this is screenshot:
[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gdN7h.png

Comment: their is a third party which lets you replace apple keyboard have a look http://fleksy.com/sdk/

Comment: Please refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556647/create-custom-international-keyboard-for-iphone