# Emoji/International Keyboard

Tags: internationalization, keyboard, ios5, emoticons

I would like to create my own emoticon keyboard in iOS 5. Would this replace the now standard emoji keyboard? In my search for answers, i havent found much on how to create/install the keyboard. From my understanding the process would be along these lines:
-create array or something of the sort (build of a keyboard template file?)
- have an app that installs this keyboard under international keyboards
- then just enable the keyboard to be available in all apps.

thanks, in advance for any help. any resources would be greatly appreciated as well

Answer (score 0):

While searching for the same thing (if there were any way to create a custom international keyboard) I found these links which say:

1. You can't create your own keyboards but only enable keyboards created by Apple.
2. If you create an app to enable other keyboards it will probably get rejected.

- [Create custom international keyboard for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6556647/661550)
- [Making An Emoji Enabeling App](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1225514/661550)