# UITextInputMode doesn't work for english decimal pad in iOS 13

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uikit, ios13, uitextinputtraits

I have two localizations in my app (English and Arabic). I have set Keyboard type for many of UITextFields to *decimalPad*. **I need to enforce English only decimal pad for these fields**. But when the app language is in **Arabic**, the keypad is shown in Arabic. It works fine till iOS 12 by subclassing UITextField and override *textInputMode*. Here is the code:

```
override var textInputMode: UITextInputMode? {
    for mode in UITextInputMode.activeInputModes {
        if mode.primaryLanguage?.containsSubString(subString: "en") {
            return mode
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

In iOS 13 the above code has no effect. I followed [Showing the system Emoji keyboard by default on iOS 13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168017/showing-the-system-emoji-keyboard-by-default-on-ios-13). Override textInputContextIdentifier but still no success.

```
override var textInputContextIdentifier: String? { return "en-US" }
```

PS: It works fine for other keyboard types - Number, Asci etc. Issue occurs for decimal pad only.