# How to open emoji keyboard by swift

Tags: ios, swift

I put a textfield on a view and if I type the textfield a keyboard will be shown. I can click on the input change button on the keyboard to change input language to emoji. Now I want to let the keyboard shown with emoji input as the default one. How can I make it on ios with swift?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the iOS keyboard layout to emoji?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382753/change-the-ios-keyboard-layout-to-emoji)

Answer (score 4):

**No this is not possible** - user can only change their language in the settings.

The Emoji keyboard is effectively a `language` setting that the user has to make and we cannot influence that.

There is a `keyboardType` property for a `UITextField`:

```
typedef enum {
    UIKeyboardTypeDefault,                // Default type for the current input method.
    UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable,           // Displays a keyboard which can enter ASCII characters, non-ASCII keyboards remain active
    UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation,  // Numbers and assorted punctuation.
    UIKeyboardTypeURL,                    // A type optimized for URL entry (shows . / .com prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad,              // A number pad (0-9). Suitable for PIN entry.
    UIKeyboardTypePhonePad,               // A phone pad (1-9, *, 0, #, with letters under the numbers).
    UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad,           // A type optimized for entering a person's name or phone number.
    UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress,           // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
    UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad,             // A number pad including a decimal point
    UIKeyboardTypeTwitter,                // Optimized for entering Twitter messages (shows # and @)
    UIKeyboardTypeWebSearch,              // Optimized for URL and search term entry (shows space and .)

    UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet = UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, // Deprecated

} UIKeyboardType;
```

Comment: Try this. It works! : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382753/change-the-keyboard-layout-to-emoji