# how to open Emoji keyboard on single button click swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

[image] Unable to show emoticon keyboard in my application on single button click
[How to open emoji keyboard by swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906547/how-to-open-emoji-keyboard-by-swift)
 my code is

```
self.textViewForChat.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage == "emoji"
```

it is not working

Comment: can you print the ful warning

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585254/call-emoji-keyboard-programmatically

Comment: As an aside, `==` is an equality operator, not an assignment operator (i.e. `=`), hence the warning shown in your screenshot.