# How to call emoji keyboard programmatically for textview

Tags: ios, swift

It is possible to trigger the emoji keyboard programmatically?

I am trying to open the emoji keyboard when the user clicks a button, it is possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the iOS keyboard layout to emoji?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382753/change-the-ios-keyboard-layout-to-emoji)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Emoji` is also considered a language keyboard, As of now Apple does not provide any public API to programmatically switch to another input method.

However there may be a workaround, This question might help:
[Change the iOS keyboard layout to emoji?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382753/change-the-ios-keyboard-layout-to-emoji)