# iOS 5: How can I disable Emoji keyboard in my application?

Tags: ios5, keyboard, emoji

I don't want the Emoji keyboard allowance in my application so I want to disable it only in my application. There is one way to do it by applying the answer from this link:

[Making An Emoji Enabeling App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225514/making-an-emoji-enabeling-app)

But this would **not** work on iOS 5 (iOS 4.3 do work). Is there any way to disable Emoji keyboard in iOS 5. Thank you.

Answer (score 39):

You can simply set the property `keyboardType` of the UITextField or UITextView to `UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable`. This disables the Emoji Keyboard for this UI element.

Comment: This will disable languages like Arabic, Hebrew, etc. however.

Comment: This does not prevent the user from copy-paste emojis in there.

Comment: What if the textField is for Email, and has to select Keyboard type as - E-mail Address ?

Answer (score 17):

@mschluepmann, But set UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable can not input Chinese

And you can do it like below

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {
        if ([textField isFirstResponder]) {
            if ([[[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage] isEqualToString:@"emoji"] || ![[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage]) { // In fact, in iOS7, '[[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage]' is nil
                return NO;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ([[[UITextInputMode currentInputMode] primaryLanguage] isEqualToString:@"emoji"] ) {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

But sometimes, the emoji may not entered by emoji keyboard. For example, when you type "哈哈" it shows  emoji on the header of the keyboard. In the case, the code above will make no effect. So you should do a twice validation as following:

```
- (BOOL)isValidString
{
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[^\\u0020-\\u007E\\u00A0-\\u00BE\\u2E80-\\uA4CF\\uF900-\\uFAFF\\uFE30-\\uFE4F\\uFF00-\\uFFEF\\u0080-\\u009F\\u2000-\\u201f\r\n]" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:self options:NSMatchingWithTransparentBounds range:NSMakeRange(0, [self length])];

    if (numberOfMatches > 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution, this should be marked as the true answer.

Comment: the isValidString method doesn't work correctly. It also blocks special characters like german umlauts (ä, ü, ö) and so on... :(

Comment: I tested this on iOS 7 & iOS 8 and it prevents Euro Symbol and french accented characters. This is a major blocker for my application and audience.

Comment: I've got the same problem. I've disabled the Emoji from the keyboard, but I saw some use did copy-past Emoji from another app (i.e: Mail). To prevent copy-past, I've found this nice extension of NSSString on Github: https://github.com/woxtu/NSString-RemoveEmoji Hope that's helps ;)

Comment: While blocking input based on the `primaryLanguage` of the current keyboard is a quick solution, it can cause some confusion since nothing will be able to be added to the text field while this check is in place and the emoji keyboard is the first responder. For example, pasting [valid] text while the emoji keyboard is open will not work. A far better solution is the category that @Lapinou posted a link to, since that checks directly against the unicode values for emoji.

Answer (score 0):

@Lapinou's answer helped me, repost his category of NSString on github: [NSString-RemoveEmoji](https://github.com/woxtu/NSString-RemoveEmoji)