# iOS Email Keyboard has Emoji button, can this be disabled?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, emoji, uikeyboardtype

When setting the keyboard in IB or programatically as below for a UITextField.

```
[textFieldOutlet setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
```

The keyboard has an Emoji icon which means you can type in Emoji's in an email address (which is a bit rubbish).  Can this be disabled?  I understand I can change the type to ASCIICapable but then I do not have the easy access to @ and . signs.

I have worked around it with this which just stops the Emoji being entered but the button is still there ([Credit Here with MeganZhou answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664134/ios-5-how-can-i-disable-emoji-keyboard-in-my-application)).

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([textField isFirstResponder])
    {
        if ([[[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage] isEqualToString:@"emoji"] || ![[textField textInputMode] primaryLanguage])
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }

    return YES;
}
```

I have also noted that the icon is there when you are typing an email address in Mail too.

This is iOS8 but may also be in earlier version.

Comment: I agree with the concept here, why would a keyboard identify as email input type, still support emoji? Kinda defeats the purpose of an email specific keyboard type imo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

User have to follow below steps if he wants to get rid of emoji button.

- Settings---> General ---> keyboard-----> Keyboards---> You'll see ENGLISH and EMOJI.
- On the top right corner is the word EDIT.
- Press EDIT, and then swipe delete to remove the EMOJI keyboard.

This will remove the emoji button and user can also have easy access to @ and . signs.

`Note`:- For security reasons, iOS does not allow programmers to remove keyboard programatically.