# Create new keyboard on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, ios6

Back in the old days, before the Emoji keyboard came standard on iOS, you could download an app that allowed you to enable and use the Emoji keyboard. Following this same concept, is it possible for me to define my own keyboard, with my own symbols that users can choose to make available in their iPhone settings?

This is for non-jailbroken iOS devices. If there's a solution for jailbroken devices, I'd take  that too (for educational purposes).

Comment: Is this for jailbroken or non-jailbroken iOS devices?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant implement a custom keyboard on a non-jailbroken iOS device which can be accessed outside your app. They were just enabling [a keyboard which was already there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225514/making-an-emoji-enabeling-app/1239449#1239449)

Basically you are not allowed to change anything outside your app. So in this case since you have to add this to settings, Apple wont allow that as per its current guidelines(Assuming that your question is about non-jailbroken iOS device where app needs to be pushed to AppStore).