# How to enable Emoji keyboard for UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, emoji, uikeyboardtype

I am creating chat application so i would like to enable Emoji keyboard for UITextView if user does not have added Emoji keyboard in keyboard settings. To achieve this I searched Google there are so many related questions but none of the answers worked for me. I am not sure why those are not worked for me. Below are the links I have followed to achieve this

**Related Questions**

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225514/making-an-emoji-enabeling-app/1239449#1239449)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225514/making-an-emoji-enabeling-app/1239449#1239449)

**My Code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableDictionary* plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:kPreferencesPlistPath];

    [plistDict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"KeyboardEmojiEverywhere"];
    [plistDict writeToFile:kPreferencesPlistPath atomically:NO];
  }
```

Also i am using `UIKeyboardTypeDefault`

Comment: You need to add Emoji keyboard in settings->Keyboard

Comment: Yes the only way is to do so is using a settings and enabling keyboard form that.

Comment: So no other way to do this right?